# Como crear una vista con JOIN reemplazando dos columnas en MySQL

Tags: mysql, select, join

Tengo la tabla fixtures asi:
[image: tabla fictures]

y tengo la tabla teams asi:

[image: tabla teams]

En fixtures las columnas local y visit corresponden a la columna teams_id de la tabla teams.
Lo que quiero es generar una vista (SELECT) que muestre fixtures pero en vez de mostrar el codigo del equipo (local, visit) mostrar sus correspondientes logos, simpre y cuando la ronda sea xxx (WHERE round=xxx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sería algo así:

```
Select f.stage, f.round, local.logo local, f.l_score, visit.logo visit, f.v_score, f.estado, f.arbitro, f.fecha, f.hora, f.l_dt 
from fixtures f
     left join teams local on f.local = local.teams_id
     left join teams visit on f.visit = visit.teams_id
where f.round = xxx
```

Resultado (provisto por Gonzalo):
[image: Resultado del Query]

Comment: Gracias Pablo funcionó a la perfección